# mostrar u ocultar los filtros al hacer click al botón dependiendo de la resolución

Tags: css, onclick, filtro, show

Tengo un botón con una función que al clicar colapsa y/o despliega un div con un formulario de filtros. 
En versión escritorio los filtros salen por defecto desplegados y al clicar el botón se colapsan.
Sin embargo, para versión movil, me gustaría que esos filtros aparecieran colapsados y al hacer clic en el botón, se desplegaran. 
Alguna ayuda?

Gracias.

Html

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById('filtros');
   var y = document.getElementById('filtros2');
    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
  x.className = "";
  y.className = "";
    } else if (x.style.display === 'none'){
        x.style.display = 'block';
  x.className = " opened";
  y.className = " opened2";
    } else{
   x.style.display = 'none';
   x.className = "";
   y.className = "";
  }

}
```

```css
.botonera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 57px;
  margin: 1em;
}
.btn {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0em;
  background-color: #297fca;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
 .btn .label {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    top: 5px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
view.view-ofertas-de-empleo .opened {  
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="botonera">
  <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
       <span class="label">Filtra las Ofertas de Empleo</span>
   </button>
  <div class="opened" id="filtros">
    <form>
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <span>Perfil Profesional</span>
          </legend>
          <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" id="edit-perfil-profesional-160" name="perfil_profesional[160]" class="form-checkbox"><label for="edit-perfil-profesional-160" class="option">Técnico/a Soporte a la Infraestructura</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="edit-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit-ofertas-de-empleo" value="Aplicar" class="button js-form-submit form-submit"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/lamenen/pen/JjoNpwd

Muchas gracias

---

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Además, también puedes hacer el [tour]. Tu pregunta no es clara. Y si te soy sincero, no a todos nos agrada hacer clic en un enlace que lleva a tu código. Intenta copiar o reproducir la parte mínima necesaria de tu código en la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos. He modificado la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasarle a través de tu javascript la opción inversa con un 'window.matchMedia': Quedaría algo así:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById('filtros');
   var y = document.getElementById('filtros2');
   var mediaqueryList = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 560px)");

    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
  x.className = "";
  y.className = "";
    } else if (x.style.display === 'none'){
        x.style.display = 'block';
  x.className = " opened";
  y.className = " opened2";
    } else{
   x.style.display = 'none';
   x.className = "";
   y.className = "";
  }

mediaqueryList.addListener( function(EventoMediaQueryList) {
if(EventoMediaQueryList.matches) {
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
  x.className = "";
  y.className = "";
    } else if (x.style.display === 'block'){
        x.style.display = 'none';
  x.className = " opened2";
  y.className = " opened";
    } else{
   x.style.display = 'block';
   x.className = "";
   y.className = "";
  }
       }
    });


}
```

```css
.botonera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 57px;
  margin: 1em;
}
.btn {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0em;
  background-color: #297fca;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
 .btn .label {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    top: 5px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
view.view-ofertas-de-empleo .opened {  
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="botonera">
  <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
       <span class="label">Filtra las Ofertas de Empleo</span>
   </button>
  <div class="opened" id="filtros">
    <form>
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <span>Perfil Profesional</span>
          </legend>
          <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" id="edit-perfil-profesional-160" name="perfil_profesional[160]" class="form-checkbox"><label for="edit-perfil-profesional-160" class="option">Técnico/a Soporte a la Infraestructura</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="edit-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit-ofertas-de-empleo" value="Aplicar" class="button js-form-submit form-submit"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

NO puedo ver exactamente como se ejecuta tu código, esta es la teoría. Espero que te haya podido ser de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias JorgeGuz, he probado a integrar tu código, pero no consigo el resultado que debería. Algo debo estar haciendo mal y no lo veo. Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda